# Run script in context of another through a package function

Tags: python

I have one directory `projects/build` which contains various files with functions, bundled up as a package with a `__init__.py` file. A second file `master_build.py` in the root, this one uses the first package. Inside `master_build.py` it iterates through the project folder to find `build.py` files which it wants to run inside the context of `master_build.py`.

If `master_build.py` uses `exec()` & pass along `global()` & `locals()` this works dandy, however I want to define this function inside the package. Running the package function from `master_build.py` then instead passes along the global & local state of the package, not the one from `master_build.py`. Naturally my question is if it's possible to some way use the context of `master_build.py` instead? Preferably without having to manually pass along `globals()` & `locals()`